# Вывод товаров для конкретного пользователя, сложный SQL запрос Laravel

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных, laravel, phpmyadmin

Необходимо вывести товары для конкретного пользователя
Назначаем какой бренд пользователь может просматривать.
Далее какие категории конкретные у данного бренда он может просматривать.
На данный момент вывожу товары только по бренду, а вот связь бренд - категории - товар не смог реализовать

`SELECT * FROM products INNER JOIN users_brands ON products.brand_id = users_brands.brand_id WHERE users_brands.user_id = 2`

Структура DB
[image: Структура базы данных]

P.S. не прошу написать запрос за меня, можно просто подтолкнуть к решению, или же привести рабочий пример

P.P.S. Да уж, БД спроектирована не наилучшим образом, довольствуемся чем есть.

Comment: что за средство для просмотра структуры?)

Comment: @programmer403 "Дизайнер" в PhpMyAdmin

Comment: @Mafftlor, я сильно не разбирался в вашем в вопросе, не пойму почему дальше не продолжили джойнить таблицы? LEFT JOIN после INNER JOIN джойните сколько вам надо а потом большой WHERE по бредну AND user=1 AND categories=1 и т.д.) простите спешу)

Comment: @programmer403 пока не совсем понимаю как это связать, сам создал вот такую структуру и мучаюсь, грубо говоря, нужно проверять каждый товар на присутствия записи в табличке users_brands - это для просмотра бренда, и одновременно доступ к категории users_brands_categories

Comment: отвечу когда домой приеду)

Comment: @programmer403 спасибо, возможно будет необходимо поменять структуру базы данных, но насколько я знаю, запрос можно написать какой угодно, главное желание)
Могу предоставить импорт базы, для детального ознакомления

Comment: да скинь мне на почту eugenemars@yahoo.com

Answer (score 0):

Вот немного набросал, если я правильно прочитал вопрос и не запутался по ходу дела, то думаю ответ подойдет.

```
SELECT * FROM users_brands
INNER JOIN users_brands_categories ON users_brands.id = users_brands_categories.users_brand_id
INNER JOIN products ON products.category_id = users_brands_categories.category_id
AND products.brand_id = users_brands.brand_id
WHERE user_id='2'
```

Вместо `SELECT *` можно сделать `SELECT products.*`

По той базе которую вы мне дали этот запрос ничего не выведет т.к. в таблице `users_brands_categories` `category_id=3` а у продукта бренд 2, а не 3й. ну думаю разберетесь

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, немного позже проверю и отпишусь